# Prove f is not measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a non-measurable set contained in $(0,1)$.

we will define

$f(x) =x\textbf{1}_{E}(x) + x^3\textbf{1}_{E^C}(x)$

where $\textbf{1}_{E}(x)$ is the indicator function for the set $E$.

Does $f$ is a measurable function?

Answer:

So I'm pretty sure the answer should be no, the function is not measurable.

But I didn't succeed prove it formally, could anyone please help me prove it formally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that $f$ is measurable on $(0,1)$. As the product of measurable functions is measurable and $1/x$ is measurable on $(0,1)$, it would follow that the function

$$ g(x):= \textbf{1}_{E}(x) + x^2\textbf{1}_{E^C}(x)$$

is measurable as well. We then obtain that the set $g^{-1}(\{1\}) = E$ is measurable, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah. That's much easier than what I was trying to do. Good job.

Comment: I wish I'd thought of that. Your answer appeared while I was typing mine at about 4 words per minute.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $E\cap (b^3,b]$ is measurable for each $b\in (0,1).$ Then let $b_0=1/2$ and for integer $n$ let $b_{n+1}=b_n^{1/3}.$ Then $E=E\cap (0,1)=E\cap \cup_{n\in Z}(b_n,b_{n+1}]=\cup_{n\in Z} (E\cap (b_n,b_{n+1}]$ is measurable. Which is false.So take some $b\in (0,1)$ such that $E\cap (b^3,b]$ is not measurable. We have $f^{-1}(b^3,b]= (E\cap (b^3,b]) \cup (E^c\cap (b,b^{1/3}]).$ If $f^{-1}(b^3,b]$ is measurable then so is  $(b^3,b] \cap f^{-1}(b^3,b]=E\cap (b^3,b].$ But it's not. So $f$ is not measurable.